# Multiple String input lengths in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a program about musical chords. I want the user to input A-G or a-g, but it can also be # or - (flat), and also m (minor).
It's running, but if you put in a#m, you get

Enter a musical piano chord name: 
A

I need it to keep reading the if statements so that if the input is 3 characters, I can delineate what that char should be.

I haven't added the section on sharps and flats yet.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Hwk9 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String chord;
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a musical piano chord name: ");
    chord = stdin.nextLine();
    String finalChord = validChord(chord);

    System.out.println(finalChord);
  }

   public static String validChord(String input) {
     if (input.length() > 3 && input.length() < 1) {
       input = "Invalid chord";
    }

    char note = input.charAt(0);
    char capNote = chordCapitalize(note);

    if (capNote == 'A') {
      input = capNote + "";
    }
    else if (capNote == 'B') {
      input = capNote + "";
    }
    else if (capNote == 'C') {
      input = capNote + "";
    }
    else if (capNote == 'D') {
      input = capNote + "";
    }
    else if (capNote == 'E') {
      input = capNote + "";
    }
    else if (capNote == 'F') {
      input = capNote + "";
    }
    else if (capNote == 'G') {
      input = capNote + "";
    }
    else {
      input = "Invalid chord";
    }

    if (input.length() == 3) {    *<<<<<<This section is not going through*
      char minor = input.charAt(2);
        if (minor == 'm') {
          input = capNote + "" + minor;
        }
        else {
          input = "Invalid chord";
        }
    }

    return input;
  }

  public static char chordCapitalize(char input) {
    String note = input + "";
    String caps = note.toUpperCase();
    char capNote = caps.charAt(0);
    return capNote;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you entering `a#m` or `A`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You're either assigning input to the uppercased version of the first letter, in which case length is 1, or making it `Invalid Chord`, in which case the length is more than 3.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are assigning the capitalized chord back to `input` in the `if` blocks. You need to have a local variable for that and *not* re-assign it to `input`

If you assign `input` the value of `capNote`, length of `input` will always be one.

```
String result;
if (capNote == 'A') {
  result = capNote + "";
}
else if (capNote == 'B') {
  result = capNote + "";
}
//Rest of code

if (input.length() == 3) { 
  char minor = input.charAt(2);
    if (minor == 'm') {
      result = capNote + "" + minor;
    }
    else {
      result = "Invalid chord";
    }
}
return result;
```

Comment: Thank you! The local variable is exactly what I was missing.